# getting out of memory error in Tensorflow 2 when using tf.data.Dataset

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I have a dataset of around 10 GB that I am trying to train.

below is the Tensorflow 2 code I am using, can someone please let me know what mistake I am making here:-

```
print("training start:", dataset_idx)
batch_size = 32

X_train = load(open(r"X_train_"+str(dataset_idx)+".pkl", 'rb'))
X_test = load(open(r"X_test_"+str(dataset_idx)+".pkl", 'rb'))

y_train = load(open(r"y_train_"+str(dataset_idx)+".pkl", 'rb'))
y_test = load(open(r"y_test_"+str(dataset_idx)+".pkl", 'rb'))
print("data loaded")

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=len(X_train)).batch(batch_size)
print("train tensor slice generated")

# Create a test dataset with batching
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test, y_test))
test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(batch_size)
print("test tensor slice generated")

model = generate_model()
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')

early_stopping_callback = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3, restore_best_weights=True)
model_checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=str(dataset_idx)+'_best_model.h5',
                                            monitor='val_loss',
                                            save_best_only=True,
                                            save_weights_only=False,
                                            mode='auto')

print("fit start")
model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=100, validation_data=test_dataset, callbacks=[early_stopping_callback, model_checkpoint_callback])
```

below is the output I am getting:-

```
training start: 0
data loaded
2023-07-30 23:19:25.203061: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-07-30 23:19:26.325477: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_process_state.cc:222] Using CUDA malloc Async allocator for GPU: 0
2023-07-30 23:19:26.329672: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1616] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3948 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5
2023-07-30 23:19:26.360992: W tensorflow/core/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:82] Allocation of 11480091200 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
2023-07-30 23:21:20.994185: W tensorflow/core/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:82] Allocation of 11480091200 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
train tensor slice generated
2023-07-30 23:21:32.009990: W tensorflow/core/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:82] Allocation of 2870303200 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
2023-07-30 23:21:49.960136: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_cudamallocasync_allocator.cc:288] gpu_async_0 cuMemAllocAsync failed to allocate 2870303200 bytes: CUDA error: out of memory (CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY)
 Reported by CUDA: Free memory/Total memory: 0/6442123264
```